# how to stop opencv2 matrix from applying mod on arithmatic result

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I have two opencv matrices A and B that have intensity values ranging from 0-255. 
I am trying to do arithmetic operations on those matrices such that 
C = A - B

```
A = cv2.imread('b.jpg',0)
B = cv2.imread('a.jpg',0)
C = np.zeros_like(A)
C = A - B
```

The problem is that if I have A[0,0] =88 and B[0,0] = 184, then C[0,0] = 160.

I am assuming what happens is that it does (88-184)%256, but is there a way to make it so that it caps at 0 or 255?

Edit: Turns out I misunderstood how numpy works with opencv2. I didn't realize that numpy arrays can change type, and that what I was looking at was an overflow issue. 
I casted my array into a float and it fixed my issues.

Comment: *always use a [python] generic tag*. If your question is *version specific*, then use a version specific tag.

Comment: That's not modding, that's overflow, so wrapping around - `88 -184 = -96` so `-96 + 256 = 160`. Use int16 probably. To cap, use `clip`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use cv2.subtract() which doesn't roll over negative integer values.